# JQuery 1.11.3 - Código não funciona dentro de função carregada em $(document).ready apenas se inserido diretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

**EDIÇÃO #1**

Descobri que o código não estava funcionando, porque este trecho de código JQuery está dentro de uma função assim:

```
var minhaFuncao = function(){
    var tbASP = [];
    var tbID = [];

    $(".portlet-body").find("div").each(function () {
        tbID.push("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
        tbASP.push($(this).data("asp"));
    });    
};
```

Só depois que eu faço:

$(function(){
    minhaFuncao();
});

**Isso não funciona!**

A saída de `console.log` é:

```
[]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array []
```

Mas se eu colocar assim:

```
$(function(){
    var tbASP = [];
    var tbID = [];

    $(".portlet-body").find("div").each(function () {
        tbID.push("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
        tbASP.push($(this).data("asp"));
    });
});
```

A saída de `console.log` é

```
[…]
    0: "#faixa-de-valor"
    1: "#ano-de-contratacao"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array []
```

### Há alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para não ter que tirar o código de dentro da função para inserir diretamente em `$(document).ready`?

---

**Original**
Tenho uma página com portlets HTML onde são renderizados gráficos HighchartsJS.

A estrutura básica da página é a seguinte:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div id="ano-de-contratacao-portlet" class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-title">
         <div class="caption caption-green">
            <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
            <span class="caption-subject text-uppercase"> Contratos Ativos - Por Ano de Contratação</span>
         </div>
         <div class="actions">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-body">
         <div id="ano-de-contratacao" data-tipo="<%=TipoRelatorios%>" data-asp="tbCarteiraAtivo_Assinatura" class="simples"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div id="origem-de-recurso-portlet" class="portlet">
      <div class="portlet-title">
         <div class="caption caption-green">
            <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
            <span class="caption-subject text-uppercase"> Contratos Ativos - Por Origem de Recurso</span>
         </div>
         <div class="actions">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portlet-body">
         <div id="origem-de-recurso" data-tipo="<%=TipoRelatorios%>" data-asp="tbCarteiraAtiva_Origem_Recurso" class="simples"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Essa estrutura HTML se repete. Eu estou usando ASP Clássico e Bootstrap 4, além de JQuery 1.11.3.

Estrutura descritiva do HTML:

`Coluna Bootstrap -> Uma DIV contêiner para o portlet (.portlet) -> Corpo do portlet (.portlet-body) -> DIV contêiner do gráfico`

Eu gostaria de pegar os IDs e o valor das propriedades `data-asp` das DIV contêineres dos gráficos usando JQuery.

Para isso eu tentei o seguinte:

```
var tbASP = [];
var tbID = [];

$(".portlet-body").find("div").each(function () {
    tbID.push("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
    tbASP.push($(this).data("asp"));
});
```

O array `tbID`, por exemplo, sempre retorna comcomprimento `0` ou comprimento `15` (que é o número de portlets da página só que com os valores `undefined`, dependendo da configuração que eu coloque.

Eu li a documentação no site do JQuery para [**.each()**](https://api.jquery.com/each/), **.map()** e [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), e, no site W3School [**.push()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp), mas não consegui resolver.

Consultei algumas páginas do StackOverflow, porém não obtive êxito:

[***Getting ID of all elements of a certain class into an array***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425661/getting-id-of-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-into-an-array)

[***How to store in Array the parent IDs of elements with the same CLASS and display in alert these stored IDs***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044748/how-to-store-in-array-the-parent-ids-of-elements-with-the-same-class-and-display): Confesso que esse aqui eu não entendi a resposta.

Pesquisei outros links no trabalho que eu não recordo agora.

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja relacionando a outra coisa, porque eu reproduzi aqui e funcionou normal. Veja neste JSFiddle que o tamanho das duas arrays retornam 2: https://jsfiddle.net/e8fvky08/

Comment: É verdade! Está funcionando perfeitamente! Eu não faço ideia do que possa ser. O console não me diz nada... Descobri! Vou fazer um update da pergunta, porque isso vai bagunçar meu código.

Comment: Do jeito que vc disse que "não funciona", aqui funcionou.

Comment: Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/e8fvky08/1/

Comment: @dvd É isso mesmo! Funcionou agora. Descobri que é porque com funções anônimas não dá pra usar antes de declarar, então a ordem importa.Obrigado pelo sua ajuda! deu certo agora.